# Slow network speeds on specific devices

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking

#### Specs:

- Killer e2600 gigabit Ethernet controller
- Qualcomm QCA9377 Wireless adapter

#### Problem

When I am using my PC (Dell G5 5000 running Windows 11), and I try to download a file off the internet (in this case I was downloading Ubuntu server), I noticed that I am getting consistently low download speeds. Now we don't have the fastest internet here (60 down, 50 up), however I feel I should be getting more than 600kbps download speeds on firefox, right?

I decided to see if this problem is specific to my computer or my entire network, so I tried to download the exact same file on an old laptop (Lenovo t440p, which is a Hackintosh), and I was getting 8mbps+! It may not be the fastest download speed but it is still quite a jump from my PC's download speed.

So, I was wondering if there is any way to fix this. The more I try to solve this problem, the more I worry it's a hardware issue. Any help would be appreciated.

#### What I have tried so far

- Download Killer control center and disable bandwidth cap (Nothing changed)
- Increase priority of Firefox in Killer control center (Slight increase, however still below 1mbps)
- Updating drivers from (No change)
- Change advanced options in the windows control panel. (No change)
- Disable firewall (No change, and yes I re-enabled firewall)
- Ditch ethernet and use WiFi (see specs for WiFi adapter) (Download speed decreased to below 500kbps)

#### Links

- [Killer WiFi drivers](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/g-series-5000-desktop/drivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done some good testing, particularly switching to Ethernet. Here are some more tests to help define the issue:

- Is the file source *limiting the speed of download by each thread*? Try a multi-threaded tool, such as [Free Download Manager](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/). If that is *very* much faster, then keep using it, or an alternative, to speed download.
- Is the machine throughput on the web slow? Try [SpeedOf.Me](https://speedof.me/), [SpeedTest.net](https://www.speedtest.net/) or similar service to check how fast is the PC internet connection, itself. If that speed is 50 or 60 MBPS, then the issue is almost certainly that the file server is restricting your download speed.
- However, if the PC connection speed is that abysmal 0.6 MBPS, then it might be hardware or software slowing thing down. Temporarily try another OS on that PC, e.g., boot from a [Live Ubuntu USB](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) -- no need to install the OS, or a browser, since it comes with Firefox installed. If that is fast, then blame Windows and its drivers; otherwise, perhaps the PC hardware has limitations.

BTW, Fire wall, and most anti-malware suites, should *not* slow download, and they provide protection needed on the web.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try all of these and keep you updated.

Comment: Multi-threaded download managers seemed to have increased the speed to 6-8 mbps! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it works. That confirms the *web sites* are throttling the connection.